# XC8 typedef struct and array

Tags: c, embedded

```
//------------------------------------------------------Experimental
typedef struct tagPCA21125_00H{ 
union  
    {                                           
    UCH8 DATA[0x0F];                                
    struct  {
                    PCA21125_00H_CTRL1_t    CTRL1;  //Byte 0
                    PCA21125_01H_CTRL2_t    CTRL2;
                    PCA21125_02H_tSec_t tSec;
                    PCA21125_03H_tMin_t tMin;   // t = time, a = alarm
                    PCA21125_04H_tHr_t  tHr;
                    PCA21125_05H_tDay_t tDay;
                    UCH8            tWeekday;
                    PCA21125_07H_tMonth_t   tMonth;
                    PCA21125_08H_tYear_t    tYear;
                    UCH8            aSec;       
                    UCH8            aMin;
                    UCH8            aHr;
                    UCH8            aWeekday;
                    PCA21125_0DH_CLKOUT_t   CLKOUT;
                    PCA21125_0EH_Timer_t    TimerCTRL;
                    UCH8            TimerData;
        };
    };
}PCA21125_t;
extern volatile PCA21125_t PCA21125;


//------------------------------------------------------Control 1
typedef struct tagPCA21125_00H{ 
union  
    {                                           
    UCH8 Byte;                      
    struct  {
                UCH8 :1;        //Bit0
                UCH8 :1;
                UCH8 h12_24:1;  // Must be 0 (alway)
                UCH8 POR_OVRD:1;                        
                UCH8 :1;                
                UCH8 STOP:1;    // Must be 0 (alway)
                UCH8 :1;                    
                UCH8 EXT_TEST:1;                        
        };
    };
}PCA21125_00H_CTRL1_t;
//extern volatile PCA21125_00H_CTRL1_t PCA21125_CTRL1;
```

The above code I was trying to implement but MPLABX XC8 complier, however did not like the tag (PCA21125_00H_CTRL1_t    CTRL1), so what I am doing wrong?, How to resolve this issue?

the compiler error as provided

```
0_Main/../5_PCA21125/PIC18_PCA21125.h:29: warning: missing basic type; int assumed
0_Main/../5_PCA21125/PIC18_PCA21125.h:29: error: ";" expected
0_Main/../5_PCA21125/PIC18_PCA21125.h:29: warning: missing basic type; int assumed
0_Main/../5_PCA21125/PIC18_PCA21125.h:30: warning: missing basic type; int assumed
0_Main/../5_PCA21125/PIC18_PCA21125.h:30: error: ";" expected
0_Main/../5_PCA21125/PIC18_PCA21125.h:30: warning: missing basic type; int assumed
```

etc etc.

Comment: No where near enough info to help: where do you think `PCA21125_00H_CTRL1_t` is declared? compiler error suggests that it *isn't*. Looks like the same applies to `PCA21125_01H_CTRL2_t` too...

Comment: John, they are basically the same form as one shown here but different name and bits, no need to include them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the typedef for `PCA21125_t` refers to the type `PCA21125_00H_CTRL1_t`, which is defined later in the file, so it's not yet defined at the point where it's referenced in the declaration of the `CTRL1` member.  If you reverse the order of the two typedefs, it might compile.

Comment: Resolved as per answer, I put the code to bottom of the struct and hey presto, it worked!